# 2 table SQL Query weird results

Tags: mysql

Ok this is driving me nuts, I need to write an SQL query that will grab product information from 2 tables. The first table 'products' contains the productId, productname, quantityperunit and unitprice. Now I can search by productname and categoryname individually, but when I try to combine the 2 I get crazy results, Here's the query:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT productId, productname, quantityperunit, unitprice FROM products pr,
categories ca WHERE pr.categoryID = ca.categoryID AND ProductName LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%'
OR CategoryName LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%'
```

excuse the java style in there, here it is formatted better:

```
SELECT DISTINCT productId, productname, quantityperunit, unitprice FROM products pr,
categories ca WHERE pr.categoryID = ca.categoryID AND ProductName LIKE '%Tofu%'
OR CategoryName LIKE '%Tofu%'
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Crazy results" doesn't tell us much.  What result did you expect, what did you get instead, and why do you think it's "crazy"?

Comment: Sorry, It just seemed random, sometimes it would just print everything, or duplicate products with categories that don't even correspond to their actual categories in the db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot tell for sure what you mean by "crazy reslust", but I guess you got many more rows than you expected.
Add parenthesis :

```
WHERE pr.categoryID = ca.categoryID AND (ProductName LIKE '%Tofu%'
OR CategoryName LIKE '%Tofu%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `LIKE`s in your two sample queries are different.

`LIKE '%Tofu%'` is very different from `LIKE 'Tofu'`.

The `%` acts like a wildcard, so `LIKE '%Tofu%'` matches `Big chunk o' Tofu and stuff` but `LIKE 'Tofu'` will not match that - it will ONLY match `Tofu`.

Which did you mean?

(also, I agree with the guy who mentioned you should check your brackets)

Comment: sorry man, just updated it, wildcard are there for both tofu's